# Rerender of parent component and its effect on children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-dom, rerender

Recently I found the following code online and got me wondering how rerender works in react. So, basically my question is that if we define a component inside of another parent functional component and the state of the parent component changes, it is clear that the parent component will rerender. But, does the child functional component defined inside of it rerender as well or it unmounts and then mounts again?
so the issue with the code below is that when a user types , the focus is lost(or  keyboard disappears in case of react-native) after every keystroke and the reason given by the author is that the child function gets redeclared when the Form function is rerendered. but I am not sure what it means by redeclared,does it mean it gets rerendered or get unmounted and get mounted again? The solution to it is either to pass {Input()} or define  outside of the parent Form compoent.
This is the link for the original article
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/code-review-avoid-declaring-react-component-inside-parent-component-1768a645f523

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Form = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(['', '']);

  const onChange = (value, index) => {
    const newValues = [...values];
    newValues[index] = value;
    setValues(newValues);
  };

  const Input = (props) => {
    return <input type='text' {...props} />;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {values.map((value, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={value}
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value, index)}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={() => setValues([...values, ''])}>Add</button>
    </>
  );
};
```